# How to solve linear equation with single variabile in C

Tags: c, algebra

To solve my program I need to solve couple of simple linear equations like the one below:

```
0,3x+(1-x)*0,6 = 0,5 * 1
```

If I solve this on paper the result is:

```
x= 0,33333
```

However I'm not sure how to do it in code. It's pretty simple to solve right side of course, however how to solve left side and then say value for single X

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure you can also have some expression with `x` on "right" side too, Am I right? I mean `2*x + 1 = x/2 - 3`.

Comment: 2nd question - do you need to read these equations from file - or you just need to represent them somehow in you program and solve?

Comment: I dont need to read it, I get inputs from user base on this I build this linear equalation.

Comment: 3rd question - do you need to present the intermediate solving steps to the program user or just need to evaluate `x`?

Comment: I have "x" just on left site, and dont need steps just final result.

Comment: 4th question - is C a must? It is quite easy to be solved in `C++` where you have polymorphism and data connected with their algorithms. In `C` it is also doable - but you end up wit bunch of pretty unreadable if/switch code....

Comment: unfortunately yea, It have to be done in C :(

Comment: is it possible to supply the inputs from user? and how you read it?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things - representation of your input data - and functions to solve it.

Let start from simple case - one `x` with some operation:

```
2 * x = 3 * 4 / 2
x + 3 = 7 - 3
```

You said in comments that right side is just some expression without `x` - so you can have treat as simple number - because you can rely on compiler to evaluate it for you.

So my idea is to do it something like this:

```
double x = solveX(mulX(2), 3 * 4 / 2);
double x = solveX(addX(3), 7 - 3);
```

How would these functions prototype look like:

```
double solveX(XExpression* expression, double valueToCompare);
XExpression* addX(double valueToAdd);
```

What is `XExpression`?

```
typedef enum XOperand
{
   XAdd,
   XSub,
   XMul,
   XDiv
} XOperand; 
typedef struct XExpression
{
    XOperand oper;
    double value;
} XExpression;
```

For such representation - implementing `solveX`and `addX` is pretty easy - first do appropriate operation based on `XOperand` (switch-code) and `addX...` just malloc and return appropriate `XExpression`.

---

Having the previous simple cases implemented - you might start thinking of more complicated expressions:

```
(2 * x - 3) / x = 103
```

You need to complicate your XExpression and solveX... And you need to create new functions `addEx, mulEx`. So my idea is to have it this way:

```
   double solveX(XExpression* expression, double valueToCompare);
   XExpression* addEx(XExpression*, XExpression*);
   XExpression* mulEx(XExpression*, XExpression*);
   ...
   XExpression* justX();
   XExpression* valueEx(double);
```

And the data definition

```
    typedef enum XOperand
    {
       XAdd,
       XSub,
       XMul,
       XDiv
    } XOperand; 
    typedef enum XType
    {
       X,
       XValue,
       XExpression,
    } XType; 
    struct XExpression;
    typedef struct XBinaryExpression
    {
        XOperand oper;
        struct XExpression* leftExpression; 
        struct XExpression* rightExpression; 
    } XBinaryExpression; 
    typedef struct XExpression
    {
        XType type;
        struct Data
        {
            double value;
            XBinaryExpression binaryExpression;   
            /* no data for X - but in multi-variable equation - you might keep here pointer to double - to one of these variables to solve */   
        } data;
    } XExpression;
```

And this example equation:

```
double x = solveX(divEx(subEx(mulX(2),valueEx(3)), justX()), 103);
```

Now, you will realize very soon - the complexity of `solveX` will be quite huge.

My final advise - do not forget about freeing all these expression

---

If you need to do something like this:

```
 double X = solveX("2x/3=4");
```

I mean parsing this equation - then what I write already is still OK - but you need to add parse code - almost as much complicated as this already presented "calculation" code.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to first parse the equation into a tree of elements (number, variable, operation) and then iterate the solution by using e.g. Newton's method.